# CNC Mill an Airfoil Shape in MasterCAM

Tags: cad, solidworks, cnc, drawings

[image]

I have this airfoil shape which I created using **MasterCam**. I used the **milling function** called MULTISURFACE. When I select the green highlighted spot above, it will throw me an error.

**Is there a way to mill the highlighted green part above along side with the entire wing surface in one single operation ?** , I used this **MULTISURFACE milling, but it did not work for me.** I have attached my MasterCAM file for your convenience, hopefully someone might be able to correct the mistake in my CAM files and re-send it to me?  I am very new to this 3D CNC Software, and mostly I done CADs only. I have uploaded the MasterCam file on google drive at [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SeBF3nJZJRPp6Esy8XWUXeANbWS-IrWE/view?usp=sharing) for download.

Comment: `it will throw me an error` ... are we supposed to guess what the error actually is? ... please add info to your post